# Include attachment in .ics file for a response to a meeting request

Tags: java, exchange-server, icalendar, activesync

I am using the following tag while creating my `ics` object;

```
Attach;FMTTYE= text/plain ;ENCODING =BASE64; VALUE =BINARY : (base 64 encoded text for a image)
```

But it seems server not able to parse the ATTACH tag - the attachment is not getting displayed in the exchange server.

Can any one tell me how to include attachment in .ics file for a response to a meeting request?

Comment: Should that FMTTYPE (typo there?) really be `text/plain` and not `image/something`? As it stands, nothing tells us the binary at the end is an image.